# CRM - SSRS FetchXML row filtering based on other rows

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm, fetchxml

I am trying to filter out some duplicate data rows in a SSRS report that I have built in Visual Studio 2015 for Dynamics and I am having some trouble with it. I have a "Code" field with data that looks like ###A and may or may not have a duplicate row like ###C. How can I filter the ###C row if the ###A row exists? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to create a separate field based on the ### portion, then I grouped by that and also set a Top N filter to grab the first occurrence.